# SMT component marked 1917C GM4YD identification

Tags: identification, components, router

Does anyone recognise this SMT component marked 1917C GM4YG? It's in the power input circuit for a 12 V, 1.5 A DC external power supply in my ZTE MC801A 5G modem/router.

The 5.5/2.1 DC socket was broken, unfortunately something else is broken also in the input PCB circuit, as there is no power on any MB ELCOs.

[image]

Comment: Do you have soldered a new DC socket onto the board? Do you have tested the resistance from the GND and +5V line from the socket input to the board-capacitors? Is the polarity correct? The possibility is high that this is an diode.

Comment: I read the marking as `1917C GM4YG` not `1917C GM4YD`.

Comment: Thanks for Your input, I have no socket, its DC036 not avilable around so oredered on Alliex 
I soldered wires, in this case plus is on right pin (top View)
I did it similar to guys fixing those modems
https://youtu.be/iJVVawoaanY?t=222
I have 12V voltage power on both sides 0 resistor but no power anywhere fahrer
6241 its a Transil TVS. 
1917C is a key for me, as no power on check solder points close to him

Comment: JYelton Thx, You right , but I think first part is a code, 1917C, what it to hell can be? 317 version ?  MikroPOwer said it can be just a diode but 6241 is a TVS Transil, and is way too much capacitors and resistors for diode, it must be a volatage regualtor chip, or Im wrong, can be too

Answer (score 0):

According to the Youtube-videos the possibility is high that this is a diode and you simply have connected the wrong wire. So check the voltage at this connector to the GND of the PCB and the shielding of the connector.

Mostly the middle pin of the socket is positive and the shielding is Ground. Check this before you go on. On the PCB the middle pin would be +12V and the two on the right and left side would be GND.